# Spring security Oauth 2 Redirect behaviour on /oauth/token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I am developing a Spring-Boot Application and the problem i have is the following:

By default, every request to my controller is redirect to /login so i cant use it that way.

I can disable /login by setting

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3
```

in the application.properties.

But I want to know how to disable it only for non-browsers, so I still can use the login.

Edit:

This would be my approach:

```
   http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .formLogin();
```

Everything what runs from /api/ is REST and should be handled by Oauth only.
The Rest should be handled by Login.

But its still not working, I am still getting the redirect.

**Never mind, fixed it. Thanks userWithLongNumber!**

In my case, it turns out my WebSecurity was misconfigured.
This works now:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

My RessourceServerConfig looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower the precedence of main application security filter.

As explained in Spring Boot tutorial.

> The @EnableResourceServer annotation creates a security filter with @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER-1) by default, so by moving the main application security to @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) we can ensure that the rule for OAuth resource takes precedence.

Setting

> security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3

does not disable the main security filter. It just changes it's priority to a lower value. ( Negative values have the highest priority. -3 has a high priority than 3)

As I understand your problem is not properly setting the matcher in the ResourceServerConfiguration. Make it more specific as following.

```
http.antMatcher("/helloOAuth")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

https://github.com/lanka-guide/simple-oauth2-server has a sample implementation. Might be helpful.